# Properly dealing with bash commands escape characters

Tags: python, linux, string, shell, scripting

In Linux Bash Scripting

- `/bin/sh` is equivalent to `/bin//sh`
- `e\tc` converts to `etc`
- `\'` converts to `'`
- `"b"` converts to `b`
- `'in'` converts to `in`

**What's a exact way to convert any string into its "bash equivalent"? (In python ideally)**

For example take `/"b"'i'n///\s"h"` which converts to `/bin/sh` as shown below:

```
r3t@r3t:~/$ /"b"'i'n///\s"h"
$
```

Comment: `//` is equivalent to `/` only in paths, in other contexts it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) module in the standard library.

```
import shlex

text = """\
/"b"'i'n///\s"h"
"""

s = shlex.shlex(text, posix=True)
list(s)
# ['/', 'bin', '/', '/', '/', 'sh']

s = shlex.shlex(text, posix=True)
"".join(s)
# '/bin///sh'
```

The above is equivalent to what you would see with bash with this input:

```
$ echo /"b"'i'n///\s"h"
/bin///sh
```

Comment: or `shlex.split(text)`